# how i can use wordpress function and plugin shortcut in ajax.php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

```
function scroll_load(){
var num_next=current_company()
//alert(num_next)
        $('#loading').css('display', 'block')
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/ajax.php?id=';?>'+num_next,
            data:{year:current_year},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(html) {

                $('#posts').append(html); 

                $('#loading').css('display', 'none')
            },
            error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                console.log( errorThrown );
            }
        });

        }
```

this is my function i get data from ajax.php but when i use wordpress functions like get_header of short cut of plugins it say fatal error any one help me thanks

Comment: Most likely wordpress isn;t include in your php file. You should be using documented methods for ajax in wordpress not using standalone files

Answer (score 0):

First off, take a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins as it provides a good overview of how to use AJAX with WordPress.

So, you'll need to add two things to your AJAX call:

1. The AJAX URL for WordPress. An easy way to get this is, if you're enqueuing your Javascript with `wp_enqueue_script()`, you can then use `wp_localize_script` to get the the AJAX URL as a variable in the footer.

   ```
    wp_localize_script( 'the-name-of-your-enqueued-script', 'ajax_url', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php') );
   ```
2. Add a parameter to your data called `action` that WordPress will use to connect it to some action on the server. I'll call it `more_posts`

Then, in your functions.php file in your theme (or in your plugin), include some add_action's to...

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_more_posts', 'more_posts_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_more_posts', 'more_posts_callback' );
```

You need both the "nopriv" and regular version so logged in and not logged in users get the same functionality.

Next, write your `more_posts_callback()` function to do whatever you need done. You can grab your `year` variable from `$_GET['year']` (assuming you're doing a GET request over AJAX)

Finally, to get your return value, `echo` your results, and then make sure to run `wp_die()`. Or, if you want to return a JSON object,  simply write `wp_send_json($return)` where `$return` is whatever you want returned from the server.

```
function more_posts_callback(){
   $year =  $_GET['year'];
   ..... // Your code to generate $return
   echo $return;
   wp_die();
}
```

Now, what this doesn't include is any data validation or authentication, such as nonces or checking that `$year` is an integer.

Comment: Thanks for your help it is useful

Answer (score 0):

Wow here is the answer if found it

For using WordPress functions like `do_shortcut()` the wp_load.php must be loaded in ajax url php file 
Here is the code should be use for example in my code in ajax.php

$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );[enter link description here](https://frankiejarrett.com/2012/04/the-simplest-way-to-require-include-wp-load-php/)

To be able to use `<?php echo do_shortcode('[ssba]'); ?>`